# Cannot find 'server\db' in sys.servers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, jobs

My SQL Server job is supposed to create a linked server and query it. However there seems to be an issue with the name and I can not figure out where. I tried googling and it seems that linked server is made, but the query "misreads" the name. Please tell why this happens or where am I messing up.

```
DECLARE @tmp_key VARCHAR(14)
 DECLARE @db cursor
 DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

exec sys.sp_addlinkedserver '[server\db]'

SET @db = CURSOR FOR
```

Here is the error part:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000'+CAST([CONro]AS VARCHAR(4)),4) 
FROM [server\db].[TKYHT].[dbo].COMPANY 
WHERE [CONro] NOT IN ('1','95','104','105','183','213','275','603','620','802','998','1001','1002',
'1105','1112','1113','1122','1179','1183','1189','1458','1508','1516','1575','1599','1602',
'1691','1841','2184','3073','3074','3980','3989','6158','6164','9990','9999') 
ORDER BY [CONro] ASC
```

The error is;

> Cannot find 'server\db' in sys.servers , Verify that the correct
>   server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure
>   sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers. [SQLSTATE 42000]
>   (Error 7202). The step failed.

Some ok code here:

```
exec sys.sp_dropserver '[server\db]'
```

Comment: Why does the job need to *create* the linked server? Can this not be set up *once* and then just *used* by the job?

Comment: No, it needs to be able to create and drop the link. I can not influence that issue.

Comment: if i run the link command and the query manually from query window, everything is peachy

Comment: Looking again at this - if all of that SQL is a single job step, then the error is because no code is executing - when it tries to *compile* the code, the linked server doesn't exist so compilation fails and no code runs. When you run it manually, are you running the create/query parts as a single query or as two separate steps?